# Secured Web service call from microsite in Exacttarget

Tags: http-post, exacttarget, ampscript

is it possible to make a Secured Webservice call from Microsite to other system? I am referring to outbound request when I am trying to call a secured web service of a third party system from a microsite. The third party has shared their client id and secret. However i am not able to hit their service using HTTPPOST2 method as below:

```
%%=HTTPPost2(@url,'application/json', @Json, true, @output,@respheader, 'client_id', 'CLient_ID_Here', 'client_secret',
```

'Client_Secret_Here','frms_tid','123232','frms_appid','SFMC','frms_source','SFMC','frms_region','TSJ1','frms_transactiontimestamp'
,'2017-07-24 14:14:31.794')=%%
But i am getting an error 400 bad request.

I reached out to salesforce team and they said "you need a CORS exception to allow a cross site reference for the web service".

I am not sure what CORS exception in and how is it relevant here. Will i have to use this CORS exception or is there any other way of making a secured web service call from microsite

Comment: i had the case reviewed with Salesforce and they confirmed that CORS is not applicable for this case. now i need to understand how to make a secured web service call from exactarget. I am using Httppost2 method but get a bad request error in response. The mulesoft team says we have to embed or refer to the Marketing cloud certificate in the call we make. How do i do that?

Comment: i have checked with SFMC. 2 way SSL connection from exacttarget is not possible